# Integral of a function and a derivative with respect to the same variable

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function

So, I have the following solution to a differential equation:

$$
y(t) = \frac{k\int \! e^{-pt} \frac{\mathrm{d}x(t)}{\mathrm{d}t} \mathrm{d}t}{e^{-pt}}
$$

But I am not sure if I can cancel out the $ \mathrm{d}t $.

What I would *like* to do is to prove that $ y(t) = k x(t) $, as I have a *hunch* that that’s the solution, but I could be wrong. (I’m working on an electrical engineering problem in which the output voltage *should* be more-or-less proportional to the input voltage, albeit shifted somewhat, etc. etc...)

I’ve tried integration by parts:

$$
\begin{align}
u &= e^{-pt} \quad& {\rm d}v &= \frac{{\rm d}x(t)}{{\rm d}t} \, {\rm d}t \\
{\rm d}u &= -pe^{-pt} \, {\rm d}t \quad& v &= x(t)
\end{align}
$$

Which yields:

$$
\begin{align}
y(t) &= \frac{k\Big( uv - \int \! v \, {\rm d}u \Big)}{e^{-pt}} \\
    &= \frac{k\Big( e^{-pt} x(t) - \int \! x(t)(-pe^{-pt}) \, {\rm d}t \Big)}{e^{-pt}} \\
    &= \frac{k\Big( e^{-pt} x(t) + p \int \! x(t) e^{-pt} \, {\rm d}t \Big)}{e^{-pt}}
\end{align}
$$

...but applying it a second time returns me to right where I started.

One thing that doesn’t help is the fact that $ x(t) = A*sin(\omega t + \phi) $, so, like $ e^x $, it never really disappears out of the integral no matter what tricks I try.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you know that $x(t)=A\sin(\omega t+\phi)$, then you know $dx/dt=A\omega\cos(\omega t+\phi)$, so you just have to figure out how to do $\int e^{-pt}\cos(\omega t+\phi)$. Call that integral, $I$. Doing integration by parts twice gets you an equation you can solve for $I$.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Wish I had seen this hours earlier... it makes a lot more sense than a lot of the other things I ended up trying, before I finally “gave up” by deciding to actually expand $x(t)$...  don’t know why I was being so stubborn in my thinking in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as Gerry Myerson pointed out, it turns out I was being silly, in that I was refusing to expand the $ x(t) $ function. Unfortunately I didn’t see his comment until a few more hours of struggling before finally finding a solution. At any rate, I figured I’d post the fully written-out process to assist any visual-learners out there who might happen to stumble across this page in the future...

The problem was that I should have just expanded the $ \frac{{\rm d}x(t)}{{\rm d}t} $ out and done the integral that way, instead of trying to use IBP with $ x(t) $ in its LHS form. If left in that form, during the *second* IBP expansion, you either end up *undoing* the first expansion (if you swap your $u$ and $dv$) or, you get $ \int \! x(t) \, {\rm d}t $, within the outermost integral, which just ends up being more of a mess than it’s worth...

This is my solution:

Given that

$$
x(t) = A*{\rm sin}(\omega t + \phi)
$$

We can solve for

$$
\int \! e^{-pt} \frac{{\rm d}x(t)}{{\rm d}t} \, {\rm d}t
$$

quite easily. First, evaluate $ \frac{{\rm d}x(t)}{{\rm d}t} $:

$$
\frac{{\rm d}x(t)}{{\rm d}t} = A * \omega * {\rm cos}(\omega t + \phi)
$$

and then just plug it into the integral:

$$
\begin{align}
\quad&\quad \int \! e^{-pt} * A * \omega * {\rm cos}(\omega t + \phi) \, {\rm d}t \\
=&\quad A \omega \int \! e^{-pt} {\rm cos}(\omega t + \phi) \, {\rm d}t,
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
u &= e^{-pt} &\quad {\rm d}v &= {\rm cos}(\omega t + \phi) \, {\rm d}t \\
{\rm d}u &= -pe^{-pt} \, {\rm d}t &\quad v &= \frac{{\rm sin}(\omega t + \phi)}{\omega},
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
\quad&\quad A \omega \Bigg( \frac{1}{\omega} e^{-pt} {\rm sin}(\omega t + \phi) - \int \! - \frac{p}{\omega} e^{-pt} {\rm sin}(\omega t + \phi) \, {\rm d}t \Bigg) \\
=&\quad A \omega \Bigg( \frac{1}{\omega} e^{-pt} {\rm sin}(\omega t + \phi) + \frac{p}{\omega} \int \! e^{-pt} {\rm sin}(\omega t + \phi) \, {\rm d}t \Bigg),
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
u &= e^{-pt} &\quad {\rm d}v &= {\rm sin}(\omega t + \phi) \, {\rm d}t \\
{\rm d}u &= -pe^{-pt} \, {\rm d}t &\quad v &= - \frac{{\rm cos}(\omega t + \phi)}{\omega},
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
\quad&\quad A \omega \Bigg( \frac{1}{\omega} e^{-pt} {\rm sin}(\omega t + \phi) + \frac{p}{\omega} \Big( - \frac{1}{\omega} e^{-pt} {\rm cos}(\omega t + \phi) - \int \! \frac{-p}{- \omega} e^{-pt} {\rm cos}(\omega t + \phi) \, {\rm d}t \Big) \Bigg) \\
=&\quad A \omega \Bigg( \frac{1}{\omega} e^{-pt} {\rm sin}(\omega t + \phi) + \frac{p}{\omega} \Big( - \frac{1}{\omega} e^{-pt} {\rm cos}(\omega t + \phi) - \frac{p}{\omega} \int \! e^{-pt} {\rm cos}(\omega t + \phi) \, {\rm d}t \Big) \Bigg) \\
=&\quad A \omega \Bigg( \frac{1}{\omega} e^{-pt} {\rm sin}(\omega t + \phi) - \frac{p}{\omega^2} e^{-pt} {\rm cos}(\omega t + \phi) - \frac{p^2}{\omega^2} \int \! e^{-pt} {\rm cos}(\omega t + \phi) \, {\rm d}t \Bigg) \\
=&\quad A e^{-pt} {\rm sin}(\omega t + \phi) - A \frac{p}{\omega} e^{-pt} {\rm cos}(\omega t + \phi) - A \frac{p^2}{\omega} \int \! e^{-pt} {\rm cos}(\omega t + \phi) \, {\rm d}t
\end{align}
$$

Which yields:

$$
\begin{align}
\quad &\quad
\Bigg( A \omega + A \frac{p^2}{\omega} \Bigg) \int \! e^{-pt} {\rm cos}(\omega t + \phi) \, {\rm d}t
= A e^{-pt} {\rm sin}(\omega t + \phi) - A \frac{p}{\omega} e^{-pt} {\rm cos}(\omega t + \phi) \\
\therefore &\quad \Bigg( \frac{\omega^2 + p^2}{\omega} \Bigg) \int \! e^{-pt} {\rm cos}(\omega t + \phi) \, {\rm d}t
= e^{-pt} {\rm sin}(\omega t + \phi) - \frac{p}{\omega} e^{-pt} {\rm cos}(\omega t + \phi) \\
\therefore &\quad \int \! e^{-pt} {\rm cos}(\omega t + \phi) \, {\rm d}t
= \frac{\omega}{\omega^2 + p^2} e^{-pt} {\rm sin}(\omega t + \phi) - \frac{p}{\omega^2 + p^2} e^{-pt} {\rm cos}(\omega t + \phi)
\end{align}
$$

So, for my ***original*** equation...

$$
\begin{align}
y(t) &= \frac{k \int \! e^{-pt} \frac{{\rm d}x(t)}{{\rm d}t} {\rm d}t}{e^{-pt}} \\
&= \frac{k A \omega \int \! e^{-pt} {\rm cos}(\omega t + \phi) \, {\rm d}t}{e^{-pt}} \\
&= \frac{k A \omega \Big( \frac{\omega}{\omega^2 + p^2} e^{-pt} {\rm sin}(\omega t + \phi) - \frac{p}{\omega^2 + p^2} e^{-pt} {\rm cos}(\omega t + \phi) \Big)}{e^{-pt}} \\
&= \frac{k A \omega^2}{\omega^2 + p^2} {\rm sin}(\omega t + \phi) - \frac{k A \omega p}{\omega^2 + p^2} {\rm cos}(\omega t + \phi)
\end{align}
$$

...which actually ended up being quite close (waveform-wise) to what I expected, so I think I’m on the right track.